# Is ScriptReference order always conserved at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager

I've been bitten in the past by `Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock`-registered JS not being emitted in a stable order from machine to machine in the bad old .Net 1.1 days.  Now, I'm writing a set of user controls that use `<asp:ScriptManager/>` to reference JS, and although I haven't had any problems so far - order always seems to be conserved between `<asp:ScriptReference>` tags - I'm feeling a bit shy about it.  MSDN seems silent on the topic, and various bloggers seem to indicate ordering is stable in .Net 2.0+, but I haven't found any definitive reference.

Does one exist?  Is the order of inclusion of scripts I observe on my development machine guaranteed to be the one I'll see in all other contexts the webapp runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further analysis concludes that the answer is that they are, at least in my particular production and development environments.